# Relative change in an oscillating quantity

Tags: error-analysis

Relative change (or fractional change) in a quantity is defined as the difference between its final and initial values divided by its initial value.

But, what would be the relative change in a quantity whose value starts oscillating? Would it be equal to the difference between its maximum and minimum values divided by its initial value?

I encountered this problem while solving a question where I was required to calculate the relative change in the angular frequency of a simple pendulum executing simple harmonic motion, when suddenly its support starts oscillating up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of relative change should work fine for a frequency which changes.  Your problem is finding the new frequency. I have a vague recollection of being told that after the system has stabilized, the frequency of a forced oscillation will be the same as that of the driving force.

Comment: Here is the exact question: A simple pendulum of length 1 m is oscillating with an angular frequency 10 rad/s. The support of the pendulum starts oscillating up and down with a small angular frequency of 1 rad/s and an amplitude of 1 cm. The relative change in the angular frequency of the pendulum is? [Am I not understanding the question properly?]

Comment: Unless your problem is from an advanced mechanics course, I'm thinking the author is the one who does not understand the problem.  For starters, with a simple pendulum the angular frequency is the square root of (g\L). Beyond that, slowly changing the position of the point of support does not change the length of the pendulum. An accelerated point of support puts the pendulum in a non-inertial frame of reference and requires a complex calculation.